# Compare Permissions of two folders at different locations

Tags: powershell, permissions, compare, directory, acl

I m trying to write a script to compare permissions of two folders at two different locations. The Folder name at both locations would be the ADID of an user and some users may have two or more AD accounts.

```
$OutPath = ".\out1.csv"

$sourcepath1 = Get-Content ".\mwd_src.txt" 
foreach ($path1  in $sourcepath1) {
    $name1 = (Get-Item $Path1).name
    $FolderAcl1 = (Get-Acl $Path1).Access | Select-Object IdentityReference

    $Source = $FolderAcl1 | Where-Object { $_.IdentityReference -like "*$name1*"} |
        Select-Object @{ Label = "Path"; Expression = { echo $Path1 } }, @{ Label = "Access"; Expression = { $_.IdentityReference } }
}

$sourcepath2 = Get-Content ".\mwd_dest.txt"
foreach ($path2 in $sourcepath2) {
    $name2 = (Get-Item $Path2).Name
    $FolderAcl2 = (Get-Acl $Path2).Access | Select-Object IdentityReference 
    $Dest = $FolderAcl2 | Where-Object { $_.IdentityReference -like "*$name2*" } |
        Select-Object @{ Label = "Path"; Expression = { echo $Path2 } }, @{ Label = "Access"; Expression = { $_.IdentityReference } }
}

$Source1 = $Source | Select-Object -Unique
$Dest1 = $Dest | Select-Object -Unique

$Out = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Source1 -DifferenceObject $Dest1
$Out1 = $Out | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -match "=>" }

foreach($OutItem in $Out1) {
    $Outitem.InputObject | Add-Content $OutPath
}
```

But getting the following error

"Compare-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'DifferenceObject' because it is null.
"

Please assist.

Comment: Does `$Dest` actually contain anything after filtering the identity references?

Comment: Yes it does when I run it alone. Both source and destination contains a same set of folders and both needs to be compared in order. Is my code right way to do that?

Comment: What is the `$_.IdentityReference -like "*$nameX*"` filter for? Also, your loops leave you with just the ACLs of the last folder from `$sourcepathX`. Is that intentional?

Comment: In the environment, folder name and ADID are same. Saved the folder name to the variable $name and checking if the same ADID has access to the folder. And the second one is not intentional. I m writing this script to compare the permissions at source and destination during migration. Say a folder XX111 is being migrated, I just want to compare if the folder at destination has same access as the one in source before deleting the source folder. But the code above was the best I could write. Any help on this ?.

Answer (score 0):

As I am missing information to your paths, I cannot reproduce your code but I tried to compare the ACLs for two local files with `Compare-Object`. I create two files which initially had the same accesses. If there is no difference, nothing is returned. I removed my account then from the permissions of the second file and got the output. (I shortened the output to avoid a horizontal bar.) The `SideIndicator` shows with the arrow to which object the difference belong.

```
InputObject                                                              SideIndicator
-----------                                                              -------------
{System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security...  =>
{System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security...  <=
```

My test code:

```
$ref = Get-Acl -Path .\Desktop\test1.txt
$diff = Get-Acl - Path .\Desktop\test2.txt

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ref.Access -DifferenceObject $diff.Access
```

I selected the `Access` property for comparison.

Regarding your error, ensure that the DifferenceObject is populated with the information you expect.